Proof for Hamming Weight Formulation
Building on this post, we conclude that the Gould's sequence A001316 is formulated as follows:
$$G(n)=\frac{2^n}{gcd(2^n,n!)}=2^{H(n)}$$
Where $H(n)$ is the Hamming weight of a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, it can be expressed as:
$$H(n)=\log_2\left(G(n)\right)=\log_2\left(\frac{2^n}{gcd(2^n,n!)}\right)$$
Or, alternatively, given that the amount of 2 factors in $n!$ is produced by the Legendre's formula, it can be rewritten as:
$$H(n)=\log_2\left(\frac{2^n}{\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^{\left\lfloor \log _2(n)\right\rfloor } \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor}\right)$$
However, I didn't find any proof for the first formulation of $H(n)$, so I would like to know how can it be proven the equivalence between the Hamming weight of a positive integer $n$ and the base-2 logarithm of the ratio between $2^n$ and its greatest common divisor with $n!$, which is given by the Legendre's $v_2(n!)$.

Can you be more explicit regarding what you want to prove? What is the exact equation you want to show?

@omer-simhi My goal is to prove the equivalence $H(n)=\log_2\left(G(n)\right)=\log_2\left(\frac{2^n}{gcd(2^n,n!)}\right)$

Where $$G(n)=\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} \bmod 2 ?$$

@omer-simhi Yes, it's the definition of the Gould's sequence $G(n)$.

@omer-simhi Yes, the remaining part is to prove such equivalence.

Based on the discussion in the comments (or by the answer from the cited post), it is left to prove that $2^{v_2(n!)} = \gcd(2^n, n!)$.  Write $n! = 2^{v_2(n!)}\cdot m$  where $m$ is an odd integer, so we get that $\gcd(2^n, n!) = 2^{\min(n, v_2(n!))}$. It is left to prove that $n\geq v_2(n!)$. This indeed hold by Legendre's formula $$v_2(n!) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^i}\right\rfloor \leq n\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} =n $$

Can you expand on the step where you write the factorial as the product with an odd integer?

@Cardstdani Sure - In general, the $p$-adic valuation of an integer $d$, $v_p(d)$, where $p$ is a prime number, is the natural number $r$ such that $p^r \mid d$ while $p^{r+1} \not \mid d$. In other words, one can write $d = p^{v_p(d)} \cdot m $ where $\gcd(m, p) = 1$. For the case where $p=2$, you get what I wrote.

@Cardstdani is the answer clearer to you now, after the comment?
